# Return result of a comparison in a query

Tags: sql

I am working on a query which is between the following tables:

tasks:

```
    id | name
  -----+-------------
   101 | MinDist
   123 | Equi
   142 | Median
   300 | Tricoloring
```

reports:

```
   id | task_id  | candidate         | score
  ----+----------+-------------------+--------
   13 | 101      | John Smith        | 100
   24 | 123      | Delaney Lloyd     | 34
   37 | 300      | Monroe Jimenez    | 50
   49 | 101      | Stanley Price     | 45
   51 | 142      | Tanner Sears      | 37
   68 | 142      | Lara Fraser       | 3
   83 | 300      | Tanner Sears      | 0
```

My output should be like:

```
    task_id | task_name    | difficulty
   ---------+--------------+------------
        101 | MinDist      | Easy
        123 | Equi         | Medium
        142 | Median       | Hard
        300 | Tricoloring  | Medium
```

And all I have done so far is this, however does not work:

```
SELECT rp.task_id, tasks.name, difficulty 
FROM tasks 
JOIN reports AS rp
WHERE   
    case when AVG(rp.score) < 20 then difficulty 'Hard' end as difficulty,
    case when 20 < AVG(rp.score) < 60 then difficulty 'Medium' end as difficulty,
    case when 60 < AVG(rp.score)  then difficulty 'Easy' end as difficulty,
GROUPBY rp.task_id;
```

and I get this error:

> Output (stderr): syntax error at or near "WHERE" LINE 5: WHERE
>           ^

Comment: please tag with the proper database platform

Comment: You need to learn SQL syntax.  You can't expect to write whatever, and expect to get answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the column in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, 
       (case when AVG(rp.score) < 20 then 'Hard'
             when AVG(rp.score) < 60 then 'Medium' 
             else 'Easy'
        end) as difficulty
FROM tasks t JOIN
     reports rp
     ON t.id = rp.task_id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name;
```

Comment: @J2015 Debugging is part of programmer's job.  You should be able to figure out this kind of thing.  There's an extra dot `.` after the alias `t`.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your output, your SQL should be

[image]

Note: Sorry, I am pasting SQL as image, as stackoverflow is giving some indentation error with the SQL query as text while I am trying to submit my comment, which I am unable to resolve.